# using hasOwnProperty () in an array

Tags: hasownproperty

Here I need only when the checked value is `true`. Now both `true` and `false` are added.

```
angular.forEach($scope.usersDetails, function(value, key) {
    if (value.hasOwnProperty('checked')) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.forEach($scope.usersDetails, function(value, key) {

    if (value.hasOwnProperty('checked') && value.checked) 
    {

    }
});
```